# How to implement the following logic with Jquery + PHP?

Tags: forms

I  have a registration form. If the user enters correct information, then I need to redirect the user to a welcome page and then ask the user to login.

Here is the design structure

1> www.xxxxx.com/signup.php => This is the webpage that the user can sign up
2> If the user enters correct information, I would like to redirect the user to a different page that presents some welcome information and require the user to login.

I don't know whether or not this welcome page is static or dynamic created. If other words,
if the welcome page is static (i.e. www.xxxxx.com/welcome.php), I should not allow the user to directly access this page unless the user has successfully signup.

How to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways.

For me easiest one would be that after signup you redirecting user to the welcome page with some query string in it - like welcome.php?signup=yes and on welcome page you check for this query string - if is missing - redirect somewhere.